# Получение списка полей формы заказа wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть кастомный плагин для wordpress.

Существует ли возможность получить список полей формы со страницы заказа в данном плагине? Интересует полный список, включая не только стандарные поля, а поля добавленные сторонними плагинами или в ручную так сказать.

Comment: название плагина то укажите, мы не экстрасенсы)

Comment: плагин в процессе разработки. У него свои отдельные задачи, в том числе получение полей формы заказа.

Comment: тогда тем более не понимаю вашего вопроса) Какие поля укажите в форме, те и получите

Comment: Давайте с другой стороны. Мне в админпанеле на определенной странице (новосозданной) необходимо отбразить все поля формы заказов. И стандартные поля и поля добавленные с помощью например WooCommerce Checkout Manager. Спискок полей  хочу получить на одной странице все вместе. Не управлять ими ненужно, просто отобразить список и допустим тип данных.

Comment: Пускай по умолчанию есть 2 поля: "имя" и "фамилия". Отредактировав файл function.php я добавил еще поле "возраст", установив плагин WooCommerce Checkout Manager я добавил поле "вес". Когда клиент добавил товар в корзину и перешол на страницу оформления заказа ему отобразились 4 поля (имя, фамилия, взраст, вес).Так вот как отобразить весь список етих полей в админке?

Comment: @Fox056 Пожалуйста, используйте поле "Ответ" для полноценных ответов на вопросы, до набора достаточной для комментирования репутации лучше избегать неясных, непонятных вопросов. Вопросов на сайте много, 50 баллов репутации - не очень большой лимит.

Answer (score 1):

Для получения полей чекаут формы WooCommerce используйте:

```
$WC_Checkout = new WC_Checkout();
$var = $WC_Checkout->get_checkout_fields();
```

Comment: Спасибо, но ета функция вернет не все поля.